# extending signatures and atoms instantiation

Tags: inheritance, extends, alloy

I am using Alloy 4.2 and I have a complexity problem using inheritance.
Apparently the inheritance between signatures does not behave as I used to face in object oriented programming (or at least as I expect).

Apparently when the exactly keyword is not set in the run command, the atoms are instantiates as the atoms of the root abstract signature even if the root abstract class is abstract.
When the exactly keyword is used to specify a command the atoms are instantiated as they are specified: leaf concrete classes.

I would like to be able to search solutions with a variability of sets that inherits from another abstract one. It allow me to specify relations in the abstract signature which then exists in the leaf signatures.

example (verbosity needs to be set to high):

```
abstract sig A {}

sig B extends A {}

sig C extends A {}

pred show {}

run show for 6 B, 6 C
run show for exactly 6 B, exactly  6 C
```

When I run the 2 predicate here are the following traces :

```
Executing "Run show1 for 6 B, 6 C"
   Sig this/B scope <= 6
   Sig this/C scope <= 6
   Sig this/A scope <= 12
   Sig this/A in [[A$0], [A$1], [A$2], [A$3], [A$4], [A$5], [A$6], [A$7], [A$8], [A$9], [A$10], [A$11]]
   Sig this/B in [[A$0], [A$1], [A$2], [A$3], [A$4], [A$5], [A$6], [A$7], [A$8], [A$9], [A$10], [A$11]] with size<=6
   Sig this/C in [[A$0], [A$1], [A$2], [A$3], [A$4], [A$5], [A$6], [A$7], [A$8], [A$9], [A$10], [A$11]] with size<=6
   Solver=minisatprover(jni) Bitwidth=0 MaxSeq=0 SkolemDepth=4 Symmetry=20
   15152 vars. 24 primary vars. 55808 clauses. 55164ms.
   Instance found. Predicate is consistent. 225ms.
```

In this execution trace we can see that all B and C are instantiated as A atoms despite A is abstract.
And we can see that B and C have pick 6 disjoint elements in the A element set.

```
Executing "Run show2 for exactly 6 B, exactly 6 C"
   Sig this/B scope <= 6
   Sig this/C scope <= 6
   Sig this/A scope <= 12
   Sig this/A in [[B$0], [B$1], [B$2], [B$3], [B$4], [B$5], [C$0], [C$1], [C$2], [C$3], [C$4], [C$5]]
   Sig this/B == [[B$0], [B$1], [B$2], [B$3], [B$4], [B$5]]
   Sig this/C == [[C$0], [C$1], [C$2], [C$3], [C$4], [C$5]]
   Solver=minisatprover(jni) Bitwidth=0 MaxSeq=0 SkolemDepth=4 Symmetry=20
   0 vars. 0 primary vars. 0 clauses. 2ms.
   Instance found. Predicate is consistent. 14ms.
```

In this trace, we can see that  the A set is composed only of B and C elements, not A elements. 
We also can see that the solving time is very different due to combinatorial explosion, even if the problem solved by the second command is simpler than the first one.

To minimise solving time, is it possible to have trace that would look like this by using fact or setting constraints on signatures?

```
Executing "Run show2 for 6 B, 6 C"
   Sig this/B scope <= 6
   Sig this/C scope <= 6
   Sig this/A scope <= 12
   Sig this/A in [[B$0], [B$1], [B$2], [B$3], [B$4], [B$5], [C$0], [C$1], [C$2], [C$3], [C$4], [C$5]]
   Sig this/B == [[B$0], [B$1], [B$2], [B$3], [B$4], [B$5]]
   Sig this/C == [[C$0], [C$1], [C$2], [C$3], [C$4], [C$5]]
```

Comment: When I execute the `run` instructions, the Analyzer shows me atoms of sigs B and C.  I assume that's what it shows you, too.  Why does it matter to you if at some stage of processing the atoms are given identifiers which reflect the fact that they are instances of signature A as well as being instances of B or C?  In other words:  what's the problem, exactly?

Comment: The problem is, if I have a relation between B->C for example, in the case of all B and C are instantiated as A elements, Alloy tries all different combination of A->A where the first A belongs to B and the second to C the complexity is about A*A. In the case of B and C are instantiated as B and C element Alloy manipulates B and C elements not A elements so the complexity is about B*C where B+C=A (because A is abstract).

Comment: The fact is that A is supposed to be abstract, meaning no concrete instance of A shall exists and Alloy instantiate B and C as A element in the first case.
In the second case if we specify B and C such that B+C=A and B&C=none we cannot specify relations in A  that automatically exists in B and C as inheritance specifies it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are not worried that Alloy is producing erroneous results, but only that it is computing them in a way that seems unnecessarily inefficient to you.  It may be easier to get a meaningful response if you describe the issue more clearly; your descriptions of how Alloy is instantiating atoms appear to me at first (and second, and third) glance to be nonsensical.  *Of course* the elements of B and C are instantiated as elements of A:  They *are* elements of A.  If they weren't, the instance wouldn't be an instance of the model you defined.

Comment: Let me try again.  You write "A is supposed to be abstract, meaning no concrete instance of A shall exist".  Not true.  In the model you define, every instance of B and every instance of C is a concrete instance of A.  The abstractness of A does not mean that A has no concrete instances, but that every concrete instance of A will also be an instance of some sub-signature of A defined using the keyword `extends`.

Comment: " every instance of B and every instance of C is a concrete instance of A" I completely agree with you. But as they are instantiated as A signature if you compare two elements of A you cannot say if its B or C. In other word the solver does not make the difference when a it manipulates B and C elements.
It needs to recalculate the type of each elements each time they must validate constraints. 
And to me each concrete instance A should be a concrete instance of its sub-signatures parting naturally the sets of the sub-signature through there type, as in POO (java for example).

Comment: Currently in the case of the small example, writing 

`run show for 6 B, 6 C` is the same thing as `run show for 12 A but 6 B and 6 C`

To me, in the first case the user explicitly specifies the atoms types (as they are instantiated with the `exactly` keyword), on the contrary  of  the second case it specify an amount for B and C that are atoms of A.

Comment: You seem to be making assumptions about the internals of the Analyzer that go well beyond anything guaranteed by the interface.  In particular, the claim that in one case but not the other "they are instantiated as A" appears to be either meaningless or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the "exactly" keyword is not used, then it is not possible to know the actual type of each atom before solving the model.  In other words, scope

```
run show for 6 B, 6 C
```

specifies only upper bounds, meaning that a valid instance is allowed to contain, for example, 2 atoms of `B` and 1 atom of `C` (depending on the actual constraints in the model).  That's why Alloy can only allocate enough atoms to start with (giving them some generic names, in this case names derived from the name of the base type), and after an instance is found, each atom will be renamed (in the visualizer) to reflect its actual type.

Only when you specify exact scopes Alloy can minimize the bounds (as you noticed) in order to potentially reduce the solving time.

Comment: ok, I understand but this policy is meaningful when super-signature are specified in the scope to search solutions and let the solver plays with the bounds. But in case of sub-signatures are specified in the scope, they should be instantiated as their types like signatures that do not have extension.